# Visual studio Project template to create a windows service in c++

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a project template available in **Microsoft Visual studio 2010** to create a windows service in c++.

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2013,you can using the ATL Project wizard to create a windows service program. And you still can set up your service class inheriting a ServiceBase class. 
[From MSDN: How to: Write Services Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76477d2t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the C++/CLI Windows Service template was removed from Visual Studio 2010. If you would like to make-use of the .Net Framework support for Windows Services, the C# version of the wizard still exists. If you would like to develop a Native windows service, you can use the ATL Project wizard and select the 'Service (EXE)' application type.